# FWPS Callouts, usages and references

Tags: windows, filter, driver, kmdf, wfp

I wanted to know the deep understanding of how `Filter Drivers` works. What is the detail and usages?

for example: `FwpsCalloutRegister` `FwpmTransactionBegin` `FwpmSubLayerAdd` `FwpmCalloutAdd` these are functions that used in many of network driver samples. Is there any reference to see how is order or what is the fundemental of `filter drivers`?

What is the usage of `FwpmSubLayer` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation:

- User Mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page
- Kernel Mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/windows-filtering-platform-callout-drivers2